# Docker with ElasticSearch none-root permission issue

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run ElasticSearch on Docker through docker-compose up. Whenever I try to start up my containers, I am getting this error:

```
 Running as non-root...
 elasticsearch    | 2017-01-06 00:08:23,861 main ERROR Could not  register mbeans java.security.AccessControlException: access denied  ("javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" "register")
  elasticsearch    |    at   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.jav       a:472)
  elasticsearch    |    at  java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:585)
  elasticsearch    |    at   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.checkMBeanTrustPermission(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1848)
  elasticsearch    |    at   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(Default MBeanServerInterceptor.java:322)
   elasticsearch    |   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
  elasticsearch    |    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.register(Server.java:389)
  elasticsearch    |    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:167)
  elasticsearch    |    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:140)
  elasticsearch    |    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:541)
   elasticsearch    |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:258)
  elasticsearch    |    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:206)
  elasticsearch    |    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:220)
  elasticsearch    |    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:197)
  elasticsearch    |    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configureStatusLogger(LogConfigurator.java:125)
  elasticsearch    |    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configureWithoutConfig(LogConfigurator.java:67)
  elasticsearch    |    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:59)
  elasticsearch    |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:89)
  elasticsearch    |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82)
  elasticsearch    | 
  elasticsearch    | 2017-01-06 00:08:25,813 main ERROR RollingFileManager (/data/elasticsearch.log) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/elasticsearch.log (Permission denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/elasticsearch.log (Permission denied)
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
    elasticsearch:
container_name: elasticsearch
image: "itzg/elasticsearch:5.1.1"
ports:
  - "9200:9200"
  - "9300:9300"
volumes:
  - "./data/elasticsearch/:/data"
```

Comment: Could you try to change this host directory ```./data/elasticsearch``` permission to ```docker``` user or ```777```?